# Regression on predicted values

Tags: poisson-regression, predictor

Friends: May I ask for your advice on an issue of statistical modelling that I have wrestled with for some time. The authors have developed a Poisson regression model using 12 risk factors (x1, x2, x3, …, x12) for predicting the risk of a disease. This development of this model was based on a large dataset.

Subsequently, the authors identified another risk factor called x13. In a smaller and somewhat independent dataset, the authors calculated the predicted probability for each individual, let's called P. Then, they used the Poisson regression model, with P and x13 as independent predictors, for predicting the risk of disease.

My question: is the approach (using P as a predictor variable) appropriate? I would appreciate your comments.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Sure, sometimes, whenever it's useful.

The estimated model from the first regression can be seen as a score, such as those used in psychology, though it is likely based on disparate variables. Applying this model to new data gives a summary of the relationship found initially.

The computed values give a new independent variable that surely affects the dependent variable. It is probably better to have it when estimating the effect of the new, added variable. The number of new observations could be much too small to give good estimates of all the independent variables in a single analysis.

The estimate of the relationship between the added independent variable and the dependent variable is likely to be somewhat different that it would be if all the variables were used in a new regression. But it's still an estimate. I would like to know if there is a literature that shows such an estimate has any standard properties, eg, on the likelihood, consistency, asymptotically unbiased, etc. It would be useful for such an estimate to have such properties.